# How can I Inject a Service into my test when my service has an injectable in its constructor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, apollo

I want to create a test script for my DataService class. I know I need to inject the service into the class but the DataService constructor takes an Apollo injectable. I've found a couple dated solutions that didn't work. Any help will be appreciated!

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

    ...

}
```

This is the test where I need the DataService:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should = chai.should();
const req = require("request-promise");
import {inject} from  "@angular/core/testing";
import { DataService } from '../data.service'

describe('User', () => {


    beforeEach(() => {

    })

    it('Can be created.', (done) => {

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to create a TestModule that has a list of providers, which are essentially the rules that Angular2 follows for *what* to inject when something is requested.

```
beforeEach(() => {

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [Apollo] // This will return an instance of the actual Apollo class (you will need to import Apollo in your spec file)
  }).compileComponents();

});
```

This will allow you to inject the Apollo service in the code being tested.  However, you may not want to inject the actual Apollo service, in which case you can create a mock apollo class, and tell the test component to inject that fake class in place of Apollo

```
class MyMockApollo {...} // should mock up any methods that your tests will rely on

beforeEach(() => {

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {provide: Apollo, useClass: MyMockApollo} // This will return an instance of MyMockApollo
    ]
  }).compileComponents();

});
```

A third option is to provide a *value* rather than a *class*

```
 providers: [
      {provide: Apollo, useValue: mockApolloInstance} // This will return the exact thing you give it
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks jason, I just tried this and I'm getting an error: "var FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec = Zone['FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec'];
                            ^
ReferenceError: Zone is not defined"

Comment: I found out that mocha/chai and angular don't get along very well. I am switching to Karma/Jasmine which is the recommended tool. Thanks for the help